# Change position of restart option radio buttons in Finished page of Inno Setup

Tags: controls, inno-setup, pascalscript

How to change the location of these controls?

The restart radio buttons do not seem to be changing its location even when you change it using `.Top`.

Here is the code:

```pascal
[Code]
procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  with WizardForm do
  begin
    { NOT WORKING }
    YesRadio.Top := ScaleY(450);
    NoRadio.Top := ScaleY(750);

    { WORKING }
    YesRadio.Left := ScaleX(200);
    NoRadio.Left := ScaleX(200);

    NoRadio.Checked := True;
  end;
end;
```

Also, if you add this code:

```
[Setup]
WizardStyle=modern
```

Both `.Left` and `.Top` do not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vertical position of the `YesRadio` and `NoRadio` are calculated just before the "Finished" page shows, based on the other contents of the page (particularly the height of `FinishedLabel` and `RunList`).

If you want to override the location, you need to do it in [`CurPageChanged` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurPageChanged):

```pascal
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = wpFinished then
  begin
    WizardForm.YesRadio.Top := ScaleY(450);
    WizardForm.NoRadio.Top := ScaleY(750);
  end;
end;
```

But make sure you know, what you are doing, not to cause the radio buttons overlap with other *dynamic* contents.